# Междоменная статистика. Как грамотно сделать?

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите как правильно реализовать задачу:
Есть несколько доменов ("кольцо" сайтов). На которое пользователи попадают и блуждают по нему. Домены разные. Потом в итоге на каком-то сайте регятся.
Задача собрать статистику своими силам с какого сайта и как они первый раз зашли прежде чем зарегится.
Казалось бы логично хранить информацию в `сессии/куках`.
Вот только как их между доменами передавать?
Как такое реализуется грамотно?

Comment: Баннер статистики на всех страницах на всех сайтах. Можно невидимый. Скрипт баннера на отдельном своем домене. Куки от этого же домена.